# Статистика в консоли разработчика

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Возникла проблема с обновлением статистики в консоли разработчика в google play, а именно на протяжении 2-х дней статистика приложения не обновляется. Возможно у кого-то были похожие проблемы и хотелось бы узнать возможно ли их решить и стоит ли подключать google Analytics чтобы решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы видите надпись "нет данных", или что-то в этом роде, значит пока что установок сделано слишком мало. Просто подождите, пока приложение наберет популярность. Обновление статистики происходит каждые 24 часа.

Google Analytics стоит ставить, если вы хотите знать, как пользователи себя ведут непосредственно в приложении.

На публично доступной странице описания Вашего приложения в Google Play, количество установок, во-первых, также отстает, а во-вторых, показывается с определенной точностью (в интервалах от..до). Например, первый интервал - *0-10*. Пока приложение не наберет 10 установок, отображаться будет *0*.

Установка считается только 1 раз для каждого Google пользователя.

Comment: А почему в описании приложения в самом магазине Google Play не показывается количество установок, хотя они уже были сделаны?

Comment: @Вячеслав смотрите обновление